# Directory Structure in PHP

Tags: php, project, project-management

The following is the direcory Structure of my application.

```
-/home/user 
| -/app
|  | -/class
|  |  |  -/proc
|  |  |   | -public_login.php
|  |  |   | -public_notice.php
|  |  |   | -public_reset.php
|  |  | -constants.php
|  |  | -utils.php
|  |  | -....
|  |  | -....
|  | -public_index.php
|  | -public_admin.php
| -public_html
  | -project_name
  | | -proc
  | | | - login.php
..........
```

Now in /public_html/proc/login.php I am including /app/class/proc/public_login.php using the following:

```
require_once('../../../app/class/proc/public_login.php');
```

Now inside the public_login.php there is requirement of app/class/utils.php
so I added the following in the public_login.php.

```
require_once '../utils.php';
```

***But I am getting 404 Error on this.***

utils.php PATH

```
/home/user/app/class/utils.php
```

public_login.php path

```
/home/user/app/class/proc/public_login.php
```

Kindly help me solve this.

Regards
**Genocide_Hoax**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realtive path is configured from the initial file doing the include/requiring so in this case `../utils.php` would evaluate to:

`/home/user/public_html/project_name/utils.php`

You can use the `__DIR__` constant to get the path to the directory of the current file so from `public_login.php` you would do:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../utils.php';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. Is there any way to call a file in app/class/proc from public_html/ideal/js/? I am using a AJAX jason here. so is there any way to call the above? Currently I had to make a copy of the proc directory inside the public_html which I don't want to do.